# Z-score without standard deviation

Tags: statistics, scoring-algorithm

I have an algorithm which implements z-score for detecting outliers. However, I am implementing this algorithm in an [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array), where I can't compute standard deviation, it is a very complex operation. Is there any possibility to use z-score without using the std? Perhaps an alternative measure?

Comment: When you say it's a complex operation, [are you referring to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Time) how many nanoseconds it'll take the hardware to compute an SD? How large is your dataset?

Comment: what exactly about computing the standard deviation is causing you difficulty? The only non-basic arithmetic operation is the square root, is that the problem?

Comment: @Set The [inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) may be more relevant, so each value being assessed doesn't cost us a division.

Comment: correct, the square root is too complex for FPGA.  The complexity there are the operations, I need to use only sums and multiplications but divisions are critical

Comment: @J.G. I have reviewed the inverse square root, but from what I see there, it does not calculate the square root of the variance, right? I mean, it calculates 1/sqrt(x)

Comment: My suggestion is to recast $z_i=(x_i-\mu)/\sigma$ as $z_i=ax_i+b$ with $a=(\sigma^2)^{-1/2},\,b=-a\mu$. You only need to compute one inverse square root, after the variance is computed. This approach also avoids numerous divisions.